# Why does the mediaPlayer class not work in this case?

Tags: java, javafx

So I'm trying to create my very own mp3 player. 
The mediaPlayer.play() method works but pause doesn't work.
Can someone help me out?

```
 public void audioPlayerButtons(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        String bip = getClass().getResource("Songs/Sing.m4a").toExternalForm();
        Media hit = new Media(bip);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);

        if (actionEvent.getSource() == playbtn) {
            mediaPlayer.play();

            nowPlaying.setText("Now Playing");
            songPlayingName.setText("Sing");

        } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == pausebtn) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();


        } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == forwardbtn) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();

        } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == backwardbtn) {
            mediaPlayer.isAutoPlay();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Which MediaPlayer are you talking about? What framework are you using?

Comment: MediaPlayer is a class https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are calling Pause on a second instance of MediaPlayer.

```
...
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
// each time you hit a button, you create a new MediaPlayer

        if (actionEvent.getSource() == playbtn) {
            mediaPlayer.play();
            // first time, you call play, so it plays
            nowPlaying.setText("Now Playing");
            songPlayingName.setText("Sing");

        } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == pausebtn) {
            // pause does work, but it is not the same instance that is playing
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    ...
```

You'll need to instantiate mediaPlayer outside the scope of that event. Try like this:

```
   // instance variables
    String bip = getClass().getResource("Songs/Sing.m4a").toExternalForm();
    Media hit = new Media(bip);
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);

public void audioPlayerButtons(ActionEvent actionEvent) {        

    if (actionEvent.getSource() == playbtn) {
        mediaPlayer.play();

        nowPlaying.setText("Now Playing");
        songPlayingName.setText("Sing");

    } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == pausebtn) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();


    } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == forwardbtn) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();

    } else if (actionEvent.getSource() == backwardbtn) {
        mediaPlayer.isAutoPlay();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much!! It took me ages to try and get my  head around it!

Comment: most likely you'll want to re-initialize it in the play, next and previousSong parts, so that it'll go to the requested song, and not to the hardcoded one, but this should give you an idea of how to start.

Comment: How should I go about doing that? I am a beginner and it's taking me hours to figure the littlest things out! Even if you could hint what I could do - it would be really really nice of you. Thanks a bunch

Comment: If you are a beginner, you should start with the beginning. What I mentioned in my previous post are (almost) the most basic things you can do in Java (some things are even easier, but still).
You should first have a good grasp at the basics, before going to more complex frameworks.

Comment: How should I allow the user to choose the song?

Comment: I don't understand how to create a play list. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: depends on how you want it. You can have a playList, and allow the user to click on an item in it, or the next button goes to either the next in the list, or to a random one (shuffle), ...